# Is it possible to change fold symbol?

Tags: vim

I want to change the fold symbol in gvim (the `+` sign in fold margin):

[image]

Is it possible? If so, how to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. It seems hard coded in Vim source.

See `:h fold-foldcolumn`.